# ecs-cli docker compose version

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to setup an ECS via ecs-cli and docker compose file. I'm using Docker compose's (version 1.6) version 2 of the Compose File format.

I'm able to create the stack via command line:

`ecs-cli up --keypair <xxx>  --capability-iam --size 5 --instance-type t2.micro`

Then when I try to create ECS definition file from docker file:

`ecs-cli compose --file aws-compose.yml create`
I get this error:

```
ERRO[0000] Error describing task definition              error=ClientException: Unable to describe task definition.
    status code: 400, request id: 593efa62-d3bc-11e5-bc6b-174f2874560f taskDefinitionName=ecscompose-expdata
ERRO[0000] Error registering task definition             error=ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id: 59482223-d3bc-11e5-bc6b-174f2874560f family=ecscompose-expdata
ERRO[0000] Create task definition failed                 error=ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id: 59482223-d3bc-11e5-bc6b-174f2874560f
FATA[0000] ClientException: Container.image should not be null or empty.
    status code: 400, request id: 59482223-d3bc-11e5-bc6b-174f2874560f
```

And I'm helpless here,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that I had some whitespaces after image name. Docker compose doesn't care, but ecs-cli is slightly more pickier. After removing them, I managed to move on

Comment: I find this utility helpful in my CI process: https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform

Answer (score 0):

Also, as of this writing [only version 1 of docker-compose is supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html):

> The ecs-cli compose command works with a Docker compose file to create task definitions and manage tasks. At this time, only Docker compose version 1 syntax is supported.

Comment: As of 07/14/2016 ecs-cli supports v2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_tutorial.html